# Is there a way to make IE6 fail gracefully when encountering '>'?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, css-selectors

It's quite well known that IE6 does not support direct descendant selection with `>`, but what I found recently is that if you have multiple selection rules separated by commas it ignores all of them if one has a `>`.

Here is the piece of code I used to test the issue:

```
<body>
    <style>
        .one, .two{
            width: 100px; 
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #FFCCAA;
        }
        body .two, body > .one{
            background-color: #CCFFAA;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>     
</body>
```

I assume (didn't read the docs) that this is expected behavior because when you write `AAA, BBB` you don't actually define two selectors, but one with two parts.

Still I have to ask... Is there any solution that doesn't imply writing my CSS rules twice?

Thank you,
Alin

P.S. Using JavaScript is not acceptable.

Comment: You do define two separate selectors, however by using a comma to group them together, it is considered one rule. The spec says that on an unrecognized selector, the entire *rule* is ignored. So indeed, IE6 is failing as gracefully as expected. The only real solution is as porneL says, to separate the selectors into their own rules :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behavior you've encountered is part of [standard CSS error recovery](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets), so IE6 is doing it right (for a browser that doesn't support CSS2).

You need to duplicate the rule, and use CSS2 selectors separately:

```
<style>
    body .two {
        background-color: #CCFFAA;
    }
    body > .one  {
        background-color: #CCFFAA;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: As I feared, this has to be the right answer. It would be helpful if you could ad a link to some official document that confirms this.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I don't believe this is possible without using Javascript.

There are some JS hacks ([Dean Edwards IE7](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) script springs to mind), but without JS the simple fact is that IE6 doesn't support it, so you can't use it.

I guess if you're prepared to do *anything* that doesn't involve JS, you could consider the Google Frame plug-in, which completely replaces the rendering engine in IE in favour of the Chrome engine. But that's a far bigger hack than anything that Javascript would ever do, so I imagine you wouldn't want to do that either.

Frankly, the best option of all would be to drop support for IE6. But I appreciate that may not be an option. (it will be good for your sanity, though)

If you do have to support IE6, the only real option you have is to put classes or IDs on everything and forget about using anything but the most basic CSS selectors.

Sorry.

Comment: I tend to make the page look pretty for the most recent browsers, and make it "work" with IE6 et al, that is, the main content should display and the navigation should display and be clickable.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but as I said, I don't want to use JS (I already knew about ie7.js). Duplicating the CSS is a better solution for me than JS at this moment. @Nathan I'm not trying to build a simple website. If that were the case I would have added classes and IDs to work around the problem.